# Add custom code for solution upgrade

Tags: 2010, feature, feature-receiver, feature-upgrade

I have a solution for SP2010. Let's call it *s.wsp*. I had version 1 of *s.wsp* and now I have version 2 of *s.wsp*. Versions 1 and 2 share three common features: A, B and C. Version 2 adds a new feature D.

We used to upgrade solutions with *Update-SPSolution* command, but now I have an error for A,B and C since we changed their paths:

> The solution cannot be deployed.  The feature 'guid_here' uses the directory "path_a" in the solution. However, it is currently installed in the farm to the directory "path_a_a". Uninstall the existing feature before you install a new version of the solution.

The idea was to add some custom code which will uninstall these features without using several calls of *Uninstall-SPFeature* command. But I have no idea is it possible or not. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check this links Different ways to achieve Feature Upgrade

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html

http://spblog.net/post/2011/05/02/How-to-upgrade-feature-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx